# ¿Cómo navegar al seleccionar un item de un navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer, navigation

Quiero saber como navegar de una activity a un fragmento o de activity a activity usando el Navigation Component desde un Navigation Drawer. Cualquiera de las dos opciones estarían bien.

**Activity del Navigation Drawer**

```
class Slide : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySlideBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivitySlideBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarSlide.toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_slide)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_slide)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()

    }
}
```

**Nav_Graph**

[image: Nav_Graph]

Comment: Si el problema es que quiero que un activity pase a otro activity mediante un `action` el cual no puede salir de un Activity (o al menos eso me da a entender ya que no me lo permite), mis activities están definidos en el `nav_graph` y tienen su id, pero no puedo hacer que un activity tenga un `action` hacía mi otra activity. ¿Es posible?

Comment: Si tienes otra pregunta deberías crear otro post. Creo que respondí tu pregunta original pero ahora haces una diferente. Respuesta corta: sí, es posible pero debes evitar tener más de una activity a menos que realmente sea necesario. Hay muy pocos casos donde sí es necesario pero puedes dar por hecho que tu caso no es uno de ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es lo mismo. Ya sea fragment, activity, dialog o cualquier otro tipo soportado, para el navigation component todos son destinations y la forma de navegar siempre es la misma. El único requisito es que estén definidos en el `NavGrap` con un id que los identifique

```
<navigation ... >

    <fragment android:id="@+id/destination_id" ... />
    ...
</navigation>
```

Del mismo modo en el layout de tu activity que contiene el navigation drawer debes tener un `NavigationView` con el atributo `app:menu` apuntando a un resource de tipo `menu` dentro del cual cada `item` debe tener su id

```
<menu ... >

    <item android:id="@+id/destination_id" ... />
    ...
</menu>
```

Cuando se ejecuta esta línea `navView.setupWithNavController(navController)`, el navigation component compara el id de los items del menu con el id de los destinations definidos en el navGraph y , si coinciden, configura automáticamente la navegación. Es decir que si quieres que un item del navigation drawer navegue por ejemplo al "fragment1", todo lo que debes hacer es darle a ese item el id "fragment1".